# My server is continuously generating below error on /var/log/httpd. any apache experts can help me in this regards?

Tags: httpd.conf, aws-ec2-instance-connect

```
[Wed Mar 04 06:56:55.957481 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13665:tid 140572492801792] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.31.9.136:30328] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)
[Wed Mar 04 06:57:18.902331 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 13807:tid 140573365217024] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.31.9.136:30338] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)
[Wed Mar 04 06:57:42.598178 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3878:tid 140572400547584] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.31.9.136:30342] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)
[Wed Mar 04 06:57:52.407308 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2900:tid 140573340038912] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.31.9.136:30316] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)
[Wed Mar 04 07:02:49.345361 2020] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3955:tid 140572996134656] (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: [client 172.31.9.136:31018] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is about timeout generate from reqtimeout module in your apache.

Try disable `reqtimeout` module from apache. (e.g. if you use debian or ubuntu, `sudo a2dismod reqtimeout`)

More information about module:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html

Or maybe this other post help you:
https://serverfault.com/questions/818891/proxy-fcgierror-70008partial-results-are-valid-but-processing-is-incomplete